# how to find the element in between two elements in a character vector created by an rtf document

Tags: r, regex, character, stringr, quanteda

I have an object created from an rtf document using the code:`sample_doc <- read_rtf("sample.doc")`  (I had to use read_rtf because the document is actually an rtf).

I know somewhere in the document there are two phrases (an element in the character vector) `apple` and `orange` and that there must be an element in between them. I just want to extract that in-between element. What should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use positive `lookbehind` and `lookahead` to target the pattern in between, this regex should give u what u need:

```
(?<=orange)(.*)(?=apple)
```